# Ruby on Rail, problemss with data save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

User has a page where he can edit his personal information(name, date of birth,...).

But the user can delete the value from the *Name* field, and then go to some link with the sidebar, and the information is saved as an empty string('').

**Question**: how do I make such a check, the user can not go to anywhere, if at least one field is empty? Or if it is empty, then fill it with the previous data?

**Controller:**

```
def editMain

    unless @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
        render_404
        return
    end

    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

    if params[:user][:first_name] == ""
        @user.errors.add(:first_name, "ERROR!")
    end

    if params[:user][:last_name] == ""
        @user.errors.add(:last_name, "ERROR!")
    end

    if params[:user][:birtday] == ""
        @user.errors.add(:birthday, "ERROR!")
    end

    @countries = Country.all
    @cities = City.all #where(country_id: @user.city.country.id)

    if @user.errors.empty?
        flash[:notice] = "Succssesful!"
    else
        render "editMain"
    end
end
```

Please, help me!

Comment: Why isn't your `User` validating its own data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use what framework gives you. You don't have to rewrite existing things.

This code =>

```
unless @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  render_404
  return
end
```

Equals to =>

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

Dont try to validate objects in controller.

This code =>

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])

if params[:user][:first_name] == ""
  @user.errors.add(:first_name, "ERROR!")
end

if params[:user][:last_name] == ""
  @user.errors.add(:last_name, "ERROR!")
end

if params[:user][:birtday] == ""
  @user.errors.add(:birthday, "ERROR!")
end
```

Equals to this =>

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = "Succesful!"
  redirect_to some_path
else
  render "editMain"
end
```

and use activerecord validations.

models/user.rb

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :birthday
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this piece of code is quite a mess:

1) 404 is returned when you can't find a page (vs you can't find a resource (user) with some id)

2) 404 is returned automatically by rails, if page (route) isn't found

3) Model should do validation (vs controller)

4) Rendering could be done for your automatically in most cases

I would really recommend to read through Getting tarted with Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html